# C Program to count substrings

Tags: c, string, substring

Why does my program always skip the last substring count?

eg1. String: `dbdbsnasdb dbdxx`

Substring: `db`

count: `4` (no error)

eg2. String: `dbdbsnasmfdb`

Substring: `db`

count: `2` (supposed to be 3)

** `#include <stdio.h>` only

```
int countSubstr(char string[], char substring[]) {
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;
    int subcount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(string);) {
        j = 0;
        count = 0;
        while ((string[i] == substring[j])) {
            count++;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        if (count == strlen(substring)) {
            subcount++;
            count = 0;
        } else
            i++;
    }
    return subcount;
}
```

and why must I declare my `j` and `count` to be `0` in the for loop? is it because `j` has to remain as `0` (substring remains the same) whenever it loops?

Comment: In the second example, the trailing null characters are matching as well, making the count one higher than the substring length.  But this code is bad, you are walking right off the end - don't do that.  And move the `strlen` calls out of the loop.

Comment: maybe `else
            i++;` is over increment.

Comment: how should I change my code?

Comment: Note that *using* `strlen()` in a loop like that is ok in PHP, but understanding [tag:c-strings] you would never do that. Instead, you would check for the `'\0'` terminator, if you know about it then `while ((string[i] == substring[j]))` would look wrong to you too.

Comment: What is the expected result for `string:ddd` with `substring:dd`? `2` or `1`?

Comment: but I thought I'm not using the right way to solve my problem? and so I need to change the way I write my code. If I knew that I'm using the wrong approach why should I continue with it? Am I correct?

Comment: should be 1 I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your inner loop (`while`) can continue to compare well past the null terminators in either strings.
   You need to stop it as soon as one of the strings reach their terminating null character.
2. Your outer loop condition has an off-by-one error. But you don't need `strlen` call anyway. Just iterate until the null character.
3. You can also move the `strlen(substring)` outside the loop to avoid potentially recalculating it.

A better version might look like:

```
int countSubstr(char string[], char substring[])
{
    int subcount = 0;
    size_t sub_len = strlen(substring);
    if (!sub_len) return 0;

    for (size_t i = 0;string[i];) {
        size_t j = 0;
        size_t count = 0;
        while (string[i] && string[j] && string[i] == substring[j]) {
            count++;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        if (count == sub_len) {
            subcount++;
            count = 0;
        }
        else {
            i = i - j + 1; /* no match, so reset to the next index in 'string' */
        }
    }
    return subcount;
}
```

Comment: 1) `)){` --> `){` 2) result of `countSubstr("ddb", "db")` is `0`.

Comment: `while (string[i]` is redundant, just testing `string[j]` is sufficient.

Comment: The case of the empty substring is handled differently: `countSubstr("", "")` should probably return 1, but your code has an infinite loop

Comment: The case of the empty substring is handled differently: `countSubstr("", "")` should probably return 1, but your code returns 0 and has an infinite loop for `countSubstr("a", "")`

Comment: Code does not compile and even with light editing still `countSubstr("ddb", "db")` is `0`.  Minor: `count = 0;` --> `size_t count = 0;`

Comment: Good improvement.  BTW: Only 1 of these 2 needed in the `while`: `string[i]` `string[j]` given the final `string[i] == substring[j]`.  Perhaps an optimizing compiler will drop one from `string[i] && string[j] && string[i] == substring[j]`?

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code:

- The loop `for (i = 0; i <= strlen(string);)` recomputes the length of the string once per iteration of the loop and you iterate one time too far.  You should instead write: `for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0';)`
- The second loop may run beyond the end of the `string`, and produce a value of `count` that is loo large: it will produce at least 3 for the second example as the null terminator is counted in all cases. This explains why you get an incorrect count of matches. The behavior is actually undefined as you are reading beyond the end of both strings.

Here is an corrected version:

```
int countSubstr(char string[], char substring[]) {
    int len = strlen(string);
    int sublen = strlen(substring);
    int i, j, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= len - sublen; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < sublen && string[i + j] == substring[j]; j++)
            continue;
        if (j == sublen)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Note that the number of occurrences of the empty string in any given string will come out as one plus the length of the string, which does make sense.

Note also that this code returns 2 for `countSubstr("bbb", "bb")` which may of may not be what you expect. The accepted answer returns 1, which is arguable.

Comment: the requirement of this program doesn't allow me to use string.h

Comment: Also (I think this is unclear) Quoted from comments: _What is the expected result for string:ddd with substring:dd? 2 or 1?_ ... _should be **1** I guess? – BEX_ Your code returns `2`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I amended the answer to clarify this point. *should be 1 I guess* hardly qualifies as a specification ;-)

Comment: as far as I'm concerned, countSubstr("bbb", "bb") = 1 is incorrect. I think this answer is better than the accepted answer, but I'm personally not a fan of loop breaks

Answer (score 1):

This works for all edge-cases I tested

```
#include <stdio.h>

int countSubstr(char string[], char substring[])
{
    int count = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    while(string[i])
    {
        int match = 1;
        size_t j = 0;
        while (substring[j])
        {
            match &= substring[j] == string[i + j];
            j++;
        }
        count += match;
        i++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Here are some test cases:

```
void test(char name[], int expected, char string[], char substring[]){
    int actual = countSubstr(string, substring);
    char* status = (actual == expected)? "PASS" : "FAIL";
    printf("%s: %s\nActual: %d\nExpected: %d\n\n",name,status,actual,expected);
}

int main(void) {
    test("Two empty strings", 0, "", "");
    test("Empty substring", 19, "sub str sub str sub", "");
    test("Empty string", 0, "", "sub");
    test("Case 1", 4, "dbdbsnasdb dbdxx", "db");
    test("Case 2", 3, "dbdbsnasmfdb", "db");
    test("No match", 0, "dbdbsnasmfdb", "dxb");
    test("Inner matching", 3, "abababa", "aba");
    test("Identity test", 1, "a", "a");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good testing.  Better to use `size_t i,j;` to well handle long strings, unlike `int i,j;`

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, you haven't check if you get past the string length.

edit:
Remember that in C all string have a '\0' at the end but in your while loop you don't check it.

On your particular example we get (starting at last db):
`i = 10, j = 0, count = 1 (check for 'd')

i = 11, j = 1, count = 2 (check for 'b')

i = 12, j = 2, count = 3 (check for '\0')

i = 13, j = 3, count = 3 (exit loop)`

count = 3 is different than strlen(substring) == 2
-> no increase on subcount

Answer (score -1):

for (i = 0; i <= strlen(string);)

Must be

for (i = 0; i < strlen(string);)

Use two for instead a very complex loop becouse it's more easy to debug .